# How to separate data in row

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySql Database, having two columns named `PageId` and `Datavalue`. The `Datavalue` column contains comma separated data. I want to split the data into rows.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you are looking for an SQL-only solution, please indicate that in your question. If you are connecting to the MySQL database using some programing language, please indicate the language/environment you are working in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store multiple values in one cell then what is the point of using a relational database ?

Here is one way you can perform this task.

You haven't even mentioned which programming language you are using to access this data, lets assume it's c#  -:

1)Read the datavalue column from the table for a given Pageid, this will store comma separated values of Datavalue into your c# variable(data) .

2)Use the function such as split in c# to extract each datavalue .
Like this

```
    string[] datavalues = data.Split(',');
    foreach (string currentData in datavalues)
    {
    //You can create a new row in other table with currentData .
    //Use a for loop to perform this action on each row of your table.
    }
```